# What is the typical $\epsilon$?

Tags: numerical-methods

In doing some self-learning in numerical methods I having come across the following a number of times.

$\epsilon$ is the smallest computational unit such that, 
$x + \epsilon = x$. 
What value does $\epsilon$ typically take?

(Am not sure if this is the correct forum for the question)

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon

Comment: Well this is in regards to numerical methods, so the accuracy is dependent on your device. For a standard calculator, you see about 8 or 9 digits. So, a good choice of epsilon would be less than of the same order of magnitude as x (I.e $10^{31} $ or something) times $10^{-9}$. Does this help or need more explaining? The general idea is it's dependent on the device you are using for calculations.

Comment: @Keegan Thank you, that was a helpful introduction,  and I am seeing a lot more detail on the site from Rahul